# Facebook chat, GTalk with XMPP?

Tags: facebook, email, xmpp, google-talk

I'm still not quite sure what XMPP is. However I understand it is a protocol which drives many IM services such as FB and GTalk.

What I'm asking is, is it possible for FB accounts to chat to other XMPP accounts (e.g. GTalk) ? Like `@hotmail.com` emails can email `@gmail.com` (decentralized) rather than only `hotmail.com` to `hotmail.com` etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly not. At least currently. Facebook does not federate, meaning it does not make or accept connections to or from other XMPP servers.

Of historical note is the fact that Google did not originally federate gmail.com. They enabled this 6 months after they launched Google Talk. There's hope for Facebook yet. Maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook does not provide an XMPP server, just an XMPP API, so it's not possible to have all the operations available at a XMPP server.

As you can see from [this link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/chat/)

> Facebook Chat should be compatible with every XMPP client, but is not
>   a full XMPP server.